# AngularJS placeholder value for select if another value is not chosen

Tags: angularjs

This is my dropdown field:

```
<select
        ng-model="$ctrl.year"
        <option value="Year" ng-selected="true">Year</option>
        <option ng-repeat="year in $ctrl.years" ng-value="year">{{year}}</option>
</select>
```

Sometimes, the model has the `year` populated, in which case I want to show that value. Sometimes, it's undefined, in which case I want to show the string "Year" as a placeholder (but not have it as a selectable option). I have read dozens of stack overflow questions and feel like I have tried everything:

- `placeholder="blah"` - doesn't do anything
- `<option value="" disabled selected>Year</option>` - always sets the placeholder to say Year, even if the model has a value
- `<option value="Year" ng-selected="$ctrl.year === undefined">Year</option>` - just adds
  "Year" as an option to the dropdown.

Comment: you should use ng-model, setting to the value you want to track. https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_databinding.asp

Comment: The second line in my post shows me setting`ng-model`. I am already doing that.

Comment: [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) will give you less trouble in the long run (even if the syntax is convoluted and impossible to remember) and you can still use a single hardcoded option with empty value for placeholder.

Comment: @ippi I updated it to use `ng-options`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Year</option>
```

This should work, if the model correctly matches a select drop-down option then it should auto select it. If it's not doing that, then your model is not correctly matching select option item. Provide a plunker with your bug and I can fix it. Remember in angular there needs to be a pointer reference to the option value and ng-model in order for it to recognize the match.

Comment: Ah the problem was that I wasn't using an {id, name} structure for my year options, I was just using an array of ints. Once I updated everything to use ids, it worked.